# How can I use the Hokuyo UTM-30LX via wifi?

Tags: ros, wifi, scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody, I'd like to know if there is a way to use the Hokuyo UTM-30LX via WiFi and, possibly, change the scan rate of the sensor.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228104/how-can-i-use-the-hokuyo-utm-30lx-via-wifi?/) by [Marty](https://answers.ros.org/users/26023/marty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you mean by using  Hokuyo via WiFi?

If it is connected to your robot or any other remote computer running ROS, you can join the same WiFi and ROS network by setting `ROS_MASTER_URI` and `ROS_IP` environment variables. Once you are connected you can get scan messages, or configure your Hokuyo using dynamic reconfigure plugin in `rqt`.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marty](https://answers.ros.org/users/26023/marty/) on 2016-03-03**:
Thank you for your reply Akif. I can access  Hokuyo via wifi generated by my robot. If I set ip_address and ip_port of the urg_node, can I get the scans of the Hokuyo from a PC connected to the same Wifi?